# How to split a string in c# using Regex?

Tags: c#

I Have a strings Like this

```
"c Name David John"

"/ . Name David John"

"Name David John"
```

I want to split it and get the output as: `David John` using Regex

Comment: Have you researched how to do this with Regex?

Comment: @dfundako yes I did, but I am unable to get the output for all types of strings as I mentioned above

Comment: Are those 3 cases every single case? You can use regex to get "Name <firstname> <lastname>"... but if its surrounded by random garbage, you'll have trouble handling all the random garbage... you need to identify every single case.

Comment: I don't see how regex will help you. Maybe split off a substring of `name` and just take what comes after?

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm Please let me know clearly how it is by using Substring

Comment: why don't you do some research on how to use `string.Split()` in C# code as well as how to use `SubString` function which is not necessary in your case.. this is not that difficult, split on the word `Name`

Comment: @SledgeHammer In my application, I will get the string  output like as I mentioned above in different cases in each case I have to separate the name of the person

Comment: @Bhargav see my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So you just take a string, and declare something to search for. And you take the substring of your full string minus what you're searching for.

```
string SearchForThis = "Name ";
string MyString = "Name jordan max";
string ResultString = MyString.Substring(MyString.IndexOf(SearchForThis) + SearchForThis.Length);
Console.WriteLine(ResultString);
```

example: http://rextester.com/PBX95443

Comment: Thanks For the Help